# Vertical UIScrollView not interactable until the contentSize exceeds visibleSize

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have noticed that with most native apps (especially Settings) you can vertically scroll the content of short pages even though their true content size is less than the visible screen space. Because all content all fits on screen, the view offset resets to zero when you release the gesture. In my app I am programmatically adding content to a vertical scroll view. Until the content takes up more space than what it visible, I cannot scroll the content up or down.

Why is this? Do I need to inflate the content size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure [`bounces`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces) is set to `true` (it is by default, so you may not need to set this) and set [`alwaysBounceVertical`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619383-alwaysbouncevertical) to `true` on your scroll view to allow vertical dragging even if the content is smaller than the bounds of the scroll view, like:

```
yourScrollView.bounces = true
yourScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

Or alternatively, in a storyboard/xib make sure these checkboxes are checked for your scroll view ("Bounce On Scroll" and "Bounce Vertically"):

[image: UIScrollView storyboard options]

(If your scroll view is meant to bounce horizontally, then of course just choose the horizontal versions of these solutions, [`alwaysBounceHorizontal`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619393-alwaysbouncehorizontal) or "Bounce Horizontally" in the storyboard.)